# How to use Next.js Link (next/link) component in a Material UI Menu?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have a Material ui menu in the following way:

```html
<Menu id="simple-menu" anchorEl={anchorEl} keepMounted open={!!anchorEl} onClose={handleClose}>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Log Out</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

and want to use  next.js `Link` tags with the`MenuItem`. What is the best way to do this?

I tried the following things:

---

The following doesn't render the `<a>` tag, but adds href to the `<li>` tag.

```html
<Link href={'#'} passHref><MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Log Out</MenuItem></Link>
```

I could add a prop to MenuItem to render `<a>` instead of `<li>` tag, however, since the menu is nested under `<ul>` tag, I'm not sure if having `<ul><a>Log Out</a></ul>` is a good idea

---

The following throws an error

```html
<MenuItem onClick={handleClose} component={<Link href={'#'}>Log Out</Link>}></MenuItem>
```

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer giving the `Link` tag within the `MenuItem` tag will work as required and for the styling issues you have to give a `textDecoration: 'none'` and `color: '#000'` within the `Link` tag to avoid the underline and blue color of the `Link` text.

```
<MenuItem>
   <Link 
      style={{
          textDecoration: 'none', 
          color: '#000'
      }}
      href="#"
   >
    Log Out
   </Link>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: `style` doesn't exist on the nextJS `<Link />` component

Comment: I went with a variation of this: `<Link style={{textDecoration: 'inherit', color: 'inherit'}}>`

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me that also disables "the regular blue link with underline in the menu":

```
<MenuItem>
    <Link href="#">
        <a
            style={{
                textDecoration: 'none',
                color: '#000'
            }}
        >
            Profile
        </a>
    </Link>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put "Link" component inside the "MenuItem" component.

```
<MenuItem><Link href="#">Log Out</Link></MenuItem>
```

Comment: This seems to work, however I get the regular blue link with underline in the menu. I think it overrides the styles? do you know if I can keep the styling of the menuitem?

Comment: @Arximede, you can change styles or change element that "Link" component renders.

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag inside link

```
<MenuItem onClick={handleClose} component={<Link href={'#'}><a>Log Out</a></Link>}></MenuItem>
```

Comment: I get an error:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Answer (score 0):

See if the below code fix this, `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object`:

```
const ALink = ({ url, linkText }) => <Link href={url}>
    <a>{ linkText }</a>
</Link>    
<MenuItem onClick={handleClose} component={ ALink({url: '#', linkText: 'Log Out') }></MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Component prop inside `<MenuItem>` is `The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a HTML element or a component.` which defauts to `<li>` as material-ui official says.

If you want to keep `<ul><li></li></ul>` structure, you have to nest your `<Link>` component inside of `<MenuItem>` component.

So this may be what you wanted.

```
<MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
  <Link href={'#'}>Log Out</Link>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers actually have it backward, which disrupts the normal layout of the `MenuItem`. (For me, the menu items became taller and the text was too low.) This worked much better, and doesn't require trying to restyle the `<a>` tag yourself:

```
<NextLink href="#" passHref>
  <MenuItem component="a">
    Log Out
  </MenuItem>
</NextLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<MenuItem key={item.href} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu} component={Link} href={item.href}>
  {item.title}
</MenuItem>
```

I have:

```
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.6",
    "next": "14.1.0",
```